# Ranger file manager: how to cycle through files

Tags: ranger

I am trying to edit my ranger config so that the "cursor" can cycle through files, meaning that basically:

- when the first item (file/directory) is selected and you press <kbd>k</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd> you go to the last file, and
- when the last item is selected and you press <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> you go back on the first file.

Does anyone know if there's a way to achieve this? I know about <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> and <kbd>G</kbd> but this seem to me a much more intuitive and fast way to get the result, as you already have your fingers on <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> (or at least I tend to).

Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to the documentation of ranger, the option is wrap_scroll.

> wrap_scroll [bool]
>
> Enable scroll wrapping - moving down while on the last item will wrap around to the top and vice versa.

Comment: I had totally missed that, thank you very much!